# Adding Section to SwiftUI ScrollView causes jerkiness

Tags: ios, swiftui

I have noticed a rather odd scroll behaviour in SwiftUI when using a `Section(header:)` in a scroll view.

Below is a very simple reproducible code (the `Year` and `month` structs are just very basic arrays and models for the purpose of creating a list of data)

```swift
struct YearTitleView: View {
    let year: Year
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text(year.year)
        }
    }
}
```

```swift
struct ScrollViewWithSections: View {
    let years: [Year]
    let cellWidth: CGFloat
    let gridItem: GridItem
    
    init(years: [Year]) {
          self.years = years
          let screenWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
          cellWidth = (screenWidth / 3)
          gridItem = GridItem(.fixed(cellWidth))
    }
    
    var body: some View {
         ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false) {
            ForEach(years, id: \.self) { year in
                LazyVGrid(columns: [gridItem, gridItem, gridItem]) {
                    Section(header: YearTitleView(year: year)) {
                        ForEach(year.months, id: \.self) { month in
                            VStack{
                                Text(month.month.description)
                            }
                            .frame(width: cellWidth, height: cellWidth)
                            .background(Color.red)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And below is the behaviour if you scroll this list.

[image]

You will notice that as you scroll, the scroll will "jerk" between sections as it appears to load the next section. If you have a large list, this behavior can seem very "disruptive" to the experience and I don't fully understand how to avoid it.

If I remove the `Section(header:)` and just include the `YearTitleView` like such

```swift
ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false) {
    ForEach(years, id: \.self) { year in
       YearTitleView(year: year)
       LazyVGrid(columns: [gridItem, gridItem, gridItem]) {
          ForEach(year.months, id: \.self) { month in
             VStack{
                Text(month.month.description)
             }
             .frame(width: cellWidth, height: cellWidth)
             .background(Color.red)
           }
        }
    }
}
```

Then the scroll experience is smooth. (and has become my current solution at this point)

I just am wondering if there was something I was doing wrong with the implementation of the `Section(header:)` which was causing the behaviour and could be avoided, or is this just one of those expected behaviours currently and will have to wait for a possible fix from Apple to improve the scroll experience when using `Sections`?

Thanks!

Comment: `LazyVGrid` does not see deep in a section (for sub-views) it loads it (lazily) as a one view - that's the reason. I think `Section` does not just fit your needs here, use instead custom header.

Comment: Ok interesting that you say it doesnt fit my needs here as I felt I was using it as its intended. I especially was hoping to use the grid layout with a pinned section header that sticks as you scroll through each section, but it seems I would need to give up that convince because of this behaviour.

Am I right that there is no other "Grid Layout" component that isn't "lazy"?

Comment: I think @Asperi meant that you should not use section, but replace it with a custom header. Your other alternative, depending on how much data/many grids is to use `VStacks` and `HStacks` that are load once, but that will use more resources especially memory than a `LazyVGrid`